# Hive line break issue

Tags: hive, accumulo

I have a hive table over an accumulo table (because we need cell level security):

```sql
CREATE TABLE testtable(rowid string, value string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.accumulo.AccumuloStorageHandler' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES('accumulo.columns.mapping' = ':rowid,c:value') TBLPROPERTIES ('accumulo.table.name' = 'testtable');
```

If i have a value which contains "/n" it conflicts with the default hive line break property which is also "/n".

for example:

accumulo insert: `insert 1 c value line\x0Abreak`

hive select: `select rowid, value, row_number() over (order by null) as rank  from testtable;`

you will get back two rows instead of one.

```
| rowid   | value  | rank  |
+---------+--------+-------+
| 2       | line   | NULL  | 
| break   | 1      | NULL  |
```

Is there any idea how can I avoid this? Thank you for all the help!

Comment: It seems you may have found a bug in the AccumuloStorageHandler for HIVE. You should file a bug report here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE

Answer (score 0):

That seems very unexpected (as the author of the AccumuloStorageHandler), but maybe I just don't know something that Hive is trying to do?

I'd file a JIRA issue for Hive over at https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa. Feel free to mention me and I can try to help write a test and get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think it is a problem from the hive side and I found a magic property which is helped: hive.query.result.fileformat (SequenceFile)